# .NET CLR Memory performance counters always show 0

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I decided to play around with performance counters in context with garbage collecting. Therefore I wrote this code:

```
 class Program
    {
        class MyInt
        {
            public MyInt(int value) => Value = value;

            public int Value { get; }
        }


        public static void Main()
        {
            const int cycles = 200000;
            var listSOH = new List<MyInt>();
            var lstLOH = new List<int>(cycles);

            for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
            {
                listSOH.Add(new MyInt(i));
                lstLOH.Add(i);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                Console.Write(".");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

The code fills up two lists with memory. Since I initialize `listLOH` with 200000 entries it should located on the Garbage Collectors Large Object Heap ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) mentions it for objects bigger 85000 bytes). With the other list `listSOH` I wanted to see what happens on the generation Small Object Heaps.

If I check the performance- `\.NET CLR Memory(HelloWorld_Net_Framework)\Large Object Heap size`-counter via perform (running as admin) it always shows the value 0. I also tried to retrieve the values via PowerShell (running as admin), same result.

```
> $samples =Get-Counter -Counter "\.NET CLR Memory(HelloWorld_Net_Framework)\Large Object Heap size" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 10
> $samples

Timestamp                  CounterSamples
---------                  --------------
31/01/2020 09:10:35        \\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\large object heap size :
                           0


31/01/2020 09:10:36        \\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\large object heap size :
                           0


31/01/2020 09:10:37        \\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\large object heap size :
                           0


31/01/2020 09:10:38        \\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\large object heap size :
                           0


31/01/2020 09:10:39        \\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\large object heap size :
                           0


31/01/2020 09:10:40        \\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\large object heap size :
                           0
```

I also have this problem with the other counters of the `.NET CLR Memory` category. Can anybody give me some advice if I've to set an registry key or something else.

**Update 1:**

Environment:

```
NET Framework 4.7.2
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041
System Type:               x64-based PC
```

**Update 2:**

If I'm using the ANT memory profiler I get correct values for the LOH and SOH:

[image]

Whats interesting, while the ANTS profiler is running I also see value in Perfmon and PowerShell:

```
> $samples =Get-Counter -Counter "\.NET CLR Memory(HelloWorld_Net_Framework)\*" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 10
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $samples[0].CounterSamples

Path                                                                                                InstanceName                      CookedValue
----                                                                                                ------------                      -----------
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\# gen 0 collections                     helloworld_net_framework                    1
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\# gen 1 collections                     helloworld_net_framework                    1
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\# gen 2 collections                     helloworld_net_framework                    1
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\promoted memory from gen 0              helloworld_net_framework                37048
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\promoted memory from gen 1              helloworld_net_framework                    0
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\gen 0 promoted bytes/sec                helloworld_net_framework                    0
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\gen 1 promoted bytes/sec                helloworld_net_framework                    0
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\promoted finalization-memory from gen 0 helloworld_net_framework                    0
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\process id                              helloworld_net_framework                14164
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\gen 0 heap size                         helloworld_net_framework              4194300
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\gen 1 heap size                         helloworld_net_framework                47144
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\gen 2 heap size                         helloworld_net_framework                   12
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\large object heap size                  helloworld_net_framework               817784
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\finalization survivors                  helloworld_net_framework                    0
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\# gc handles                            helloworld_net_framework                   22
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\allocated bytes/sec                     helloworld_net_framework                    0
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\# induced gc                            helloworld_net_framework                    1
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\% time in gc                            helloworld_net_framework 7.32466043442964E-05
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\# bytes in all heaps                    helloworld_net_framework               864940
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\# total committed bytes                 helloworld_net_framework               888832
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\# total reserved bytes                  helloworld_net_framework             33546240
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\# of pinned objects                     helloworld_net_framework                    5
\\laptop-f273g581\.net clr memory(helloworld_net_framework)\# of sink blocks in use                 helloworld_net_framework                    0
```

Can anybody explain to me, why Perfmon/PowerShell is working while ANT is running?

Thx

Comment: Doesn't these counters only make sense from within the process? I am unfamiliar with these counters to be honest, but if you have 10 .NET applications running, you have 10 LOHs in play. You're querying the counters for the Powershell application.

Comment: I thought it what be interesting to check the counters from outside to e.g. check for memory leaks.

Comment: Nothing special is needed to enable this counter.  Just do this another way to ensure the plumbing works.  Run perfmon.exe > Performance Monitor > right-click the graph > Add Counters.

Comment: Not sure about memory counters, but CPU counters sometimes become broken and rebuilt registry cache is required, `lodctr /r` from command line